# Check when file is finished downloading in python (socket programming)

Tags: python, file, sockets, server, client

How could I keep track of the progress of  a file download using socket programming with TCP client/server logic to continue code flow without a infinite while loop?

Comment: It is not even clear what protocol is used to download the file. Some protocols like HTTP might send the total length up-front (but not in all cases) while others will not and the end of the file is just the close of the connection. There are simply too few details known about your specific use case and where exactly you have the problem.

Comment: TCP client/server logic in socket programming.

Comment: There is no generic file transfer in socket programming and such no generic answer can be given.

Comment: Please clarify. 'Keep track of' isn't necessarily the same thing as 'check when file is finished downloading'.

Answer (score -1):

If you can parse the headers manually you can get the file size, in `content-length` field, total iterations will be content_length / recv_buffer_size. For example if you receive 1024 bytes at a time and file size is 4096, then number of iterations = 4096/1024 = 4.

```
    total_length = content_length / buffer_size
    progressbar.set_length(total_length)   #some imaginary library
    for i in range(total_length):
      data = socket.recv(buffer_size)
      if data :
        file.write(data)
        progressbar.update(1)   #some imaginary progress-bar library
    file.close()
```

Comment: What about client (opposite) side of code? Like sending the content length etc

Comment: The total iterations are undefined. There is nothing in HTTP or TCP that guarantees it, or that any given read will fill the buffer.